# Understanding why the expectation is over the new policy $\pi'$ in the proof of the Policy Improvement Theorem

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proofs

In reinforcement learning, policy improvement is a part of an algorithm called policy iteration, which attempts to find approximate solutions to the Bellman optimality equations.

Pages 84 and 85 in Sutton and Barto's [book](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Esutton/book/bookdraft2016sep.pdf) on RL mentions the following theorem:

> **Policy Improvement Theorem**
>
> Given two deterministic policies $\pi$ and $\pi'$, then $$v_\pi(s) \leq q_\pi(s, \pi'(s)), \forall s \in S.$$
>
> where $S$ is the set of all states.

In the the right-hand side of the inequality, the agent acts according to policy $\pi'$ (given that $\pi'(s)$ is used in the inequality), in the current state $s$, and for all subsequent states acts according to policy $\pi$.

In the left-hand side of the inequality, the agent acts according to policy $\pi$ (hence the subscript $_\pi$ of $v_\pi(s)$), starting from the current state $s$.

The claim is the following

> $$v_\pi(s) \leq v_{\pi'}(s), \forall s \in S$$

In other words, $\pi'$ is is an improvement over $\pi$.

However, I have a difficulty in understanding the proof. This is discussed below.

> **Proof**
>
> $$v_\pi(s) \leq q_\pi(s, \pi'(s)) = \mathbb{E}_{\pi'}[R_{t+1} + \gamma v_\pi(S_{t+1}) \mid S_t = s]$$

I am stuck here. The q-function is evaluated over the policy $\pi$ (note the subscript $_\pi$ in $q_\pi(s, \pi'(s))$). That being the case, *how is the expectation over the policy $\pi'$*?

My guess is the following. In the proof given in Sutton and Barto, the expectation is unrolled in time. At each time step, the agent follows the policy $\pi'$  for that particular time step, and then follows $\pi$ from then on. In the limit of this process, the policy transforms from $\pi$ to $\pi'$. As long as the expression for the return inside the expectation is finite, the governing policy should be $\pi$; only in the limit of this process does the governing policy transform to $\pi'$.

Answer (score 3):

The expectation is over the policy $\pi'$ because the action at the state $S_t = s$ is taken according to $\pi'$, **and**, for the proof, the book text (2nd edition, paragraph below Equation 4.8) defines $\pi'$ to be a policy that is identical to $\pi$ except that $\pi'(s) = a \neq \pi(s)$, where $s$ is one particular state.

So, essential, the book text tries to prove that, for such a changed policy $\pi'$, if $q_\pi(s, a) = q_\pi(s, \pi'(s)) > v_\pi(s)$, then the changed policy is better than $\pi$. Note that $\pi'(s) = a$ in this case.

That is why $q_\pi(s, \pi'(s)) = \mathbb{E}_{\pi'}[R_{t+1} + \gamma v_\pi(S_{t+1}) \mid S_t = s]$.